# How to use a structure block & structure void?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I searched the wiki for info, but I can’t understand about it.

> When placed, use the structure block to open the structure block GUI. The GUI opens only if the player is in Creative mode, and has the proper permissions. Once a structure is named, its name appears above the structure block when highlighted, preceded by the block mode (e.g. "Save:House").‌

And what is GUI?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure blocks are how you can save a certain region of blocks to a file or load from files into your world. A GUI is a graphical user interface, sort of like the thing that opens when you open a chest.

When the wiki says:

> When placed, use the structure block to open the structure block GUI. The GUI opens only if the player is in Creative mode, and has the proper permissions.

It means:

You can right-click on the structure block to open its interface. You can only do so if you are in Creative Mode and have the proper permissions.